# I want to import a csv to use as filter in the powershels gci command

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with extension and description.
I want to import that file and use it as the filter parameter in a gci command.
But I get no results.

I expect to get a list of the jpg files but get no results.

```
$extensions=Import-CSV -Path c:\scripts\Media-extension-foto.csv 
#$extensions=Import-CSV -Path c:\scripts\Media-extension-foto.csv -header extension

$extensions.extension

$src = "c:\scripts\"
#gci c:\scripts\ -Include $Extensions.extension #-Force -recurse
#gci c:\scripts\ -filter $Extensions.extension #-Force -recurse
gci c:\scripts\|where{$_ -like $extensions.extension}`
```

my csv file looks like this (just made a small file for testing)

```
extension,"description"
*.JPEG,JPEG Image
*.JPF,JPEG 2000 Image
*.JPG,JPEG Image
*.JPG_LARGE,Twitter Large JPEG Image
```

There are jpg files in that folder :

```
    Directory: C:\Scripts

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          23/11/2022    11:02         509592 nieuw9754560_02-10.jpg
-a---          23/11/2022    11:02         576486 nieuw9754560_02-15.jpg
-a---          23/11/2022    11:02         641802 nieuw9754560_02-20.jpg
-a---          23/11/2022    11:01         705702 nieuw9754560_02-25.jpg
-a---          23/11/2022    11:01         763249 nieuw9754560_02-30.jpg
```

Comment: If you use `-Recurse`, it should work: `gci c:\scripts\ -Include $Extensions.extension -Recurse -Force`. Without `-Recurse`, append `*` to the input path, because `-Include` only matches agains the names of the _input_ path(s): `gci c:\scripts\* -Include $Extensions.extension` Apart from that, there's no obvious problem with your code.

Comment: Actually, there is _one_ problem: `$_ -like $extensions.extension` won't work as intended, because only a _single_ pattern is supported on the RHS of `-like`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this - I think all you're missing is changing the $_ to $_.Extension for the Get-ChildItem, on the last line.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't directly fix the code but here's another way of getting the result using `foreach` to iterate through each extension in the array:

```
foreach($e in $extensions.extension) {
 gci c:\scripts\ | where {$_ -like $e} 
}
```

Comment: this would be querying the same folder when there is no reason for it. the `foreach` should be inside the `where-object` scriptblock

Comment: The reason is it works, though I understand it may not be as performant as desired. Can't seem to get it to work with `foreach` inside `where-object`.